# When I click a button that leads to another page, how do I get the contents of the new page?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using `selenium-webdriver` to scrape a website. When the browser clicks the "Next" button, the next page loads, but when I try to find the elements I want, the driver prints contents from the previous page.

Here's my script:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
url = 'http://www.airforwarders.org/companies'
page = driver.navigate.to(url)

driver.find_elements(:css=>'.item_main').each{|div|
    puts div.text 
}

paginationToolbar = driver.find_element(:css=>'.pagination-toolbar')
paginationToolbar.find_elements(:css=>'.btn')[-2].click # Clicking the "next" button
driver.find_elements(:css=>'.item_main').each{|div|
    puts div.text # This shows the same stuff from the previous loop
}
```

If I can get the contents from the new page, this would be no problem. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure, that Selenium had clicked on the button the next page is loaded, then I think you should add `sleep 1` after click.

Comment: Please don't do `sleep`s... the proper way is to wait for an element on the new page to be accessible. That way your script doesn't break when 1 second isn't enough and goes faster when you don't need a full second.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly ajax wasn't finished on the moment after the click action.
Try to wait 1-3 seconds before doing additional actions.